# Cheap gigabit switch?

Tags: gigabit-ethernet

Does anyone have any recommendations for a cheap gigabit switch?  I'm starting to outgrow my WRT54GL router.

Comment: Are you looking for a router with a gigabit switch integrated into it or just a switch?

Comment: I'd say this was Sysadmin related

Comment: Why was this closed? It seems a sensible question. Anyhow I recommend the Belkin entry level switches. After all Dell rebadge them and sell them as PowerConnects! I have several and if you just want a simple unmanaged switch they are perfect.

Comment: This seems like a fine question to me...

Comment: I cannot even remotely recommend anything related to Dell PowerConnects. I came up with a "brick the PowerConnect" procedure that involved actually using some of the webadmin settings. After denying it for months and then looking at it for months, Dell quietly decided to not fix the problem.

Comment: Why did this get closed?  It's a simple question that people were willing to answer and it seems enough sysadmin-related to be valid.  Geez.

Comment: Voted to reopen, I agree with the above, this is a valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume this is a home or small-office arrangement as you are currently using a consumer AP+Switch like the WRT54GL, in which just about any switch would do aside from some of the dirt cheap imports. At home I have a simple 5 port netgear gigabit switch and it works without fault at speeds that suggest my machines are the bottleneck not the switch.

Such a switch should connect to your router as an uplink device, essentially extending it rather than replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a TP Link TL-SG1005D 5 port Gigabyte switch for around US$35.

http://www.tplink.com/products/product_des.asp?id=69